# rsync --delete possible when choosing filenames?

Tags: bash, rsync

I'd like to be able to have rsync copy files I have listed in my bash script and then delete any files that do not exist in the source directory (if i change the file list in the script).  Expanded the command looks like this:

```
rsync -axSR --delete src_dir1/file1 src_dir2/file2 dst_dir/
```

However, rsync is not deleting extraneous files.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

With this syntax, it could be because you are using multiple sources, and those sources are actual files.

Why not just sync the parent directory of `src_dir` to `dst_dir`?

Comment: Well the `src_dir` would actually be several different folders and could require a lot of different files to be copied.

Comment: Typically, that's use case of `rsync`, keeping 2 separate filetrees in sync. If you're backing up individual files, you may want to ditch rsync, and instead, maintain a list of files to backup, copy over files to the `dst_dir` based on the list, and then delete any files in the `dst_dir` not on the list.

Comment: Yeah, thanks Chris.  Looks like the way I'll have to go.  Had thought to use the cp prog but was just a bit curious and hoping to save a bit of time.  Thanks for help.